# Cassandra out of memory heap

Tags: node.js, cassandra, bigdata, nosql

I have 4 cassandra nodes in cluster and one column family which has 10 columns where row cannot grow very wide (maybe max 1000 columns).

I have "peak" writes where I insert up to 500 000 records in 5-10 minutes range.

I use node.js driver: [node-cassandra-cql](https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql)

3 nodes are working fine but one node crashes every time on heavy writes.

All nodes currently have around 1.5 GB data size and problematic node has 1.9 GB data size.

All nodes have max heap space at 1GB (I have 4 GB RAM on machines so default cassandra config file calculated this amount of heap)

I use default cassandra configuration except I increased write/read timeouts.

**Question**: Does anyone knows what could be reason for this?
Is heap size really that small?
What and how to configure cassandra cluster for this use case (heavy writes at small time range and other time actually doing nothing or just small writes)

I haven't tried to increase heap size manually, first I would like to know if maybe there is something other to configure instead just increasing it.

Comment: What operating system? What Cassandra version? Are you using vnodes? how did you configure row caching?

Comment: Also what is your data model?

Comment: That heap configuration (4 x 1 GB in 4GB RAM) is pushing the limits. You might shrink it a little.

Comment: Are you using Batches?